# Why Consumer thread is not able to remove messages from Vector?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to create a solution for Producer/ Consumer problem where one thread is putting message in Vector and another is removing from it.

```
import java.util.Vector;
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    static final int MAXQUEUE = 5;
    private Vector<String> messages;

    public Producer(Vector<String> messages) {
        super();
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) 
                putMessage();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private synchronized void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE) {
            wait();
        }
        messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
        System.out.println("put message");
        notifyAll();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        Vector<String> messages = new Vector<String>();
        new Thread(new Producer(messages)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(messages)).start();
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{
    public Consumer(Vector<String> messages) {
        super();
        this.messages = messages;
    }
    private Vector<String> messages;

    public synchronized String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        notifyAll();
        while (messages.size() == 0) {
            wait();//By executing wait() from a synchronized block, a thread gives up its hold on the lock and goes to sleep.
        }
        String message = (String) messages.firstElement();
        messages.removeElement(message);
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String message = getMessage();
                System.out.println("Got message: " + message);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I am running the program, it is printing  put message 5 times. I don't understand even after notifyAll(), it is not giving lock to consumer.

Comment: This may not be the issue, but try putting the main method inside another driver class?

Comment: You are putting as fast as you can until it is full, I wouldn't be surprised if the consumer cannot obtain the lock until the producer call wait().

Comment: BTW Using a BlockingQueue would be much simpler and more efficient as the producer doesn't lock out the consumer. i.e. you can have concurrent adding and removing.

Comment: Also note: the remove first element is more expensive as you add more elements and using a Vector which was replaced in 1998 adds no value over using a collection such a LinkedList or Queue.

Comment: @Peter What small change I can do to make it work? I can't use any concurrent api data structure.

Comment: Unless you deliberately slow the producer outside synchronized or by waiting, it is highly likely the queue will fill before the consumer has a chance to consume anything.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Which is not a problem, because when the producer has filled the queue, it'll start waiting. The problem is use of **disparate monitors**. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416689/5221149).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because your two threads are not notifying/waiting on the same monitor.

They each notify and wait on their own monitor, not a shared monitor. Change code to use a shared monitor, e.g. `messages`, including the synchronizations.

```
private void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (messages) { // <======
        while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE) {
            messages.wait();  // <======
        }
        messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
        System.out.println("put message");
        messages.notifyAll(); // <======
    }
}

public String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (messages) { // <======
        while (messages.size() == 0) {
            messages.wait();  // <======
        }
        String message = (String) messages.firstElement();
        messages.removeElement(message);
        messages.notifyAll(); // <======
        return message;
    }
}
```

Notice that methods are no longer synchronized.

Comment: Can't we do it using Synchronized method instead of Synchronized block?

Comment: @Vicky No, because synchronized method is the same as `synchronized (this) {`, which means that the two classes are synchronizing on two different objects.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I am getting the issue now. In this case, "this" is the Thread object, right?

Comment: @Vicky `this` is the `Producer` or `Consumer`, not the `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Logging to the console is very slow so if you do this without holding the lock you give the consumer a chance.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            // slows the producer a little to give the consumer a chance to get the lock.
            System.out.println("put message");
            putMessage();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized  (messages) {
        while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE) {
            messages.wait();
        }
        messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
        messages.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

BTW on the consumer you can write this

```
public String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (messages) {
        while (messages.isEmpty()) {
            messages.wait();//By executing wait() from a synchronized block, a thread gives up its hold on the lock and goes to sleep.
        }
        messages.notifyAll();
        return messages.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vicky he is right, you need to synchronise the collection which is the shared object not the Runnable.